# Homotopy of two paths whose composition is nullhomotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $f, g$ be two paths in a space such that their concatenation $f * g$ is nullhomotopic. Prove that $f$ is homotopic to $g$ rel $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: You can't prove it, because it's not true.

Comment: To elabore on Ryan's comment: Your statement becomes ture when you have to replace $g$ with its reversed path.

Answer (score 3):

As Rasmus points out, once you state the result correctly, it's easy -assuming you've already proved some elementary properties of homotopy.

Namely, let $f,g$ be two loops with $f(0) = g(0) = f(1)= g(1) = x_0$ and such that $g^{-1}*f \sim 1$, where $1$ is the constant path at $x_0$.

Then $f\sim 1* f \sim (g*g^{-1})*f \sim g* (g^{-1}*f) \sim g*1  \sim g$.

**Exercise.** Which "elementary properties of homotopy" have we used and where?